# TFS 2017 Extension on pull request - How to get data from the parent host?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-rest-api

I've created an extension in TFS2017. It's basically a tab to display the linked workitems with some details on the selected pull request. 
[image]

The problem is that I'm unable to get the id and other data that are needed to use them as parameters in order to use call the method [getPullRequestWorkItems()](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/versioncontrol/gitrestclient/githttpclient2_2#method_getPullRequestWorkItems) which basically gets the work items on the current pull request.

The method VSS.getWebContext() doesn't provide the needed data, and I've tried to do something like window.parent.location.href but this is not because I get error like securityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Thanks

**Edit:**
I have installed the contribution guide extension to get the availabe context and configuration data but the configuration is empty:
[image]

**Update:**

I could solve this task using the getConfiguration() as suggested by Eddie - MSFT. 
This requires updating TFS to 2017.1RC2 if you are the extension running onprem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [getConfiguration()](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/core-sdk#method_getConfiguration) method to get the Pull Request ID and Repository ID.

By the way, there is a [Contributions Guide](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-samples.samples-contributions-guide) extension you can use to help you develop the extension more easily. For example, after you install this extension, you will find what the information you can get:
[image]

Comment: I have installed the contribution guide extension but the configuration is empty?! It seems to be working in VSTS but not on TFS2017?

Comment: @Sam00 Then did you get any data if you use getConfiguration() method in your extension?

Comment: I have inserted the getConfiguration() method in my extension but it returns just an empty object :(

Comment: @Sam00 I can reproduce this issue at my side on TFS2017 and have help you submit an issue here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/22210/getconfiguration-method-cannot-get-any-data-under.html. Product team will check the issue and provide some feedback, you can track the status from there.

Comment: I have just installed the new TFS2017.1_RC2 and the getConfiguration() method seems to work as on VSTS

Comment: @Sam00 Glad to hear that.